# Mapping values to stacked bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart, visualization

I have a dataset in Json format looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "Year": 2002,
    "gender": 2,
    "age": "Adult",
    "relationship": "Family/Relative",
    "population": 0
  },
  {
    "Year": 2002,
    "gender": 2,
    "age": "Adult",
    "relationship": "Family/Relative;Other",
    "population": 0
  },
  {
    "Year": 2002,
    "gender": 2,
    "age": "Adult",
    "relationship": "Family/Relative;Unknown",
    "population": 0
  },
  {
    "Year": 2002,
    "gender": 2,
    "age": "Adult",
    "relationship": "Friend",
    "population": 0
  },
```

The year is until 2017 and for the age, there are Adult, Minor and Unknown which only show Adult here. I want to make a stacked bar chart and the "relationship" as X axis, the age as the Stack of the bar showing different kind of age range and the y axis as the Populations. here is my code sofar:

```
var margin = {top:0, right:40, bottom: 50, left: 60},
            width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

state = {year: 2002, gender: 2};


var svg = d3.select('#main')
       .append("svg")
       .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
       .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
       .append("g")
       .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.json('./relationship.json').then(years => {

var dataset = d3.stack()(["Adult", "Minor", "Unknown"].map(function(age) {
  return years.map(function(d) {
    return {x: d.relationship, y: +d[age]};
  });
}));
 var xScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(dataset.map(function(d) { return d.x; }))
  .rangeRoundBands([10, width-10], 0.02);

svg.append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
   .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale))
   .selectAll("text")
   .text(d => getRange(d))
   .attr("transform", "translate(-10,0)rotate(-45")
   .style("text-anchor", "end");

});
```

I have something wrong with the mapping step and I don't know how to map the data to the stack. And keep throwing out error saying "map not defined" etc. What is the correct way to do in D3.V5?

Comment: Can you share your project on codesandbox?

Comment: @TopW3 I don't know how to use codesandbox, but I share it on jsfiddle, here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/nk1bdmg7/ but I don't know how to put data there

Comment: Looking at the mapping of the `years` array to the dataset: `return {x: d.relationship, y: +d[age]};` - For `y: +d[age]`, this will return the year at the value of the variable `age` - one of  "Adult", "Minor", "Unknown". Possibly you meant to use `y: +["age"]`, since `d["Adult"]` would not return a meaningful value. Also using `+` would try to coerce it to a number.

Comment: I change it to y: +["age"] but it threw out an error saying "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: d3.scaleOrdinal(...).domain(...).rangeRoundBands is not a function" seems like the d3.scaleOrdnal  is use incorrectly.

Comment: Either way, adding `+` would try to convert a string value, for example - `"Adult"`, to a number. Converting a string to a number will always result in the value `NaN`. Which numerical value are you trying to get from each object in the array?

Comment: I want to map the get the population